# PHP JSON conversion from doctrine entity with nested objects

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

So i have the following and can't seem to covert it to a normal JSON format, I am using JMS Serializer for APIs in the FOSRestBundle.

My line that gets sent to JMS Serializer is

```
return array(
            'fields' => $entities,
    );
```

$entities includes all the info below, what you see below is a

```
print_r($entities);
```

Output:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset Object
        (
            [fieldid:Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset:private] => 43
            [title:Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset:private] => Genre
            [formid:Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset:private] => 1
            [choicestext:Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset:private] => Array
                (
                     [0] => stdClass Object
                         (
                            [label] => Folk
                         )

                )

            [defaultval:Test\ClientBundle\Entity\Fieldset:private] => 0
        )
)
```

When i use the built in JMS Serializer i get this:

```
{"fields":[{"fieldid":43,"title":"Genre","choicestext":"Array","defaultval":"0"}]
```

The problem is that choicestext has no nested JSON object but just a string "Array", how can I make the code insert it so it can be read as nesteed JSON object, is there a trick with JMS Serializer?

This is the actual array that gets inserted into the object property choicestext:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => Folk
        )

 )
```

When printed as JSON using json_encode it comes out as:

```
[{"label":"Folk"}]
```

So that is correct, just don't see why when inserted in that entities it doesn't work?

UPDATE:

```
print_r(json_encode($entities));
```

Result:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

Comment: What happens if you just `json_encode()` this data structure?

Comment: @MikeBrant just posted the output you wanted, i am suspecting it might have to do with doctrine having certain properties in the actual entity such as choicestext as a string from the database

Comment: `json_encode` cannot access the properties of the entity, because they are private. Therefore you get an array with six empty JSON objects.

Comment: @lxg correct, i would have to create a separate object basically copying the content of the entity object.

Comment: @HardFitness: Or, you could work with the entity metadata.

Comment: @lxg so i was able to get my copy of entity into an object working. But for some reason JMS Serializer doesn't like if i don't use the actual entity object. If you want to place a solution with the entity that should be good :) thx

Comment: What column type is `choicestext`?

Comment: @lxg its string
@ORM\Column(name="ChoicesText", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the choicestext field is defined as string:

```
@ORM\Column(name="ChoicesText", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
```

The serializer uses the entity metadata to determine the data type of the field. As it thinks that the field contains a string, it simply casts the current value to a string. If you want choicestext to be a string, don't set it to an array value.

Comment: i think i have to stick to using JMS Serializer bundle to modify my data to get accepted in the API. I want choicestext to be an array but it can't be as the property is a string.

Comment: Can't you set the column type to `array`?

Comment: No, the type is based on what the sql database has. So choicestext is a string `ChoicesText` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

Comment: Uhm, Doctrine's `array` type is also a string in the database. Doctrine handles serialization/unserialization on the fly. So, simply define the field as `@ORM\Column(type="array")`, and you're good. (By the way, when using Doctrine, it doesn't matter what the DB supports. If Doctrine supports it, you don't have to worry. Unless you're using native queries through Doctrine, of course.)

Comment: I tried that but gave me a string as well.
  foreach($entities as $entity) {
         if($entity->gettypeof() == "checkbox") {
          $entity->setchoicestext($choices_array); 
         }
        }

ended up showing "Array" for choicestext

Comment: Have you updated the schema after changing the column type? `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete` (Also, you'd have to update all existing values in that column like `UPDATE foo SET bar = 'a:0:{}'`.)

Comment: Unfortunately i am working with a database that I can modify the types or fields. Using it just for reading and writing entries but not allowed to change the structure for table. And all entries for that column are now strings so it would break if it was some array and some strings.

Comment: Gonna try to serialize the copy of $entities that I created and see if that works but for POST i think either there has to be a lot of code in between or change the types in database which I am sure client won't want to.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform the $entities into a array structure first. This can be done by this function I wrote:

```
/**
 * transforms any object into a array structure
 *
 * @param Object $object
 * @return array
 */
protected function _objectToArray($object)
{
    $array = array();

    foreach ((array) $object as $key => $value) {
        // is the value a object? transform it to a array itself
        if (is_object($value)) {
            $array[$key] = $this->_objectToArray($value);
        } else {
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

and then transform it into a JSON-string. It might come out strange structured if there are multiple level with different types of elements (array, objects, etc.). But you can always use the standard PHP array functions to extract the information you need easily.

Comment: tried that but it came out real weird. Just need to get into the $entities the array as a real array not as a string.

Comment: Yeah, it might come out strange structured if there are multiple level with different types of elements (array, objects, etc.). You can always use the standard PHP functions to extract the information you'd like to have easily from the array. If the result is too strange I'd probably build a adapter to transform it.